# How to find $k$ smallest elements with least comparisons, if $m$ elements can be compared each time?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Say I'm given a subroutine that can sort at most $m$ elements each time it get called, which is treated as a black box.
Now, I'm further given a set of $N$ elements. The task is to find the smallest $k$ elements in the list.

What is the minimum number of times calling the subroutine needed, at least asymptotically? How would an efficient algorithm look like?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: k<m<N ? or m<k<N?

Comment: I would to like work with k<m<N first